# How to ignore class during MongoDB serialization?

Tags: c#, mongodb, inheritance, serialization, discriminator

In my model I have two classes:

```
class A
{
    int PropertyA { get; set; }
}
class B : A
{
    int PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

In my app I need to instantiate B as A and use PropertyB if the object is of B type. Into Db I don't need this, and anyway I only need to store A's members. If I set to ignore B's properties, the driver adds in any case a discriminator _t because the actual type is different from declared type and I don't want to store it.
Is there a way to say at MongoDb's driver to ignore B class from serialization?

Comment: I have no clue how to do this, but it sounds like something is wrong with your model. Generally speaking, serialization should re-create the original state, and downcasting an object is certainly not the same state. I'd suggest you handle that in your application code, e.g. using a class that contains only the information you want stored in your DB and do the mapping either manually, or using something like AutoMapper.

Comment: I need the B class to store with the A object some business logic data hiding these infos to other code, which use the object only as an A instance. An other solution could be create a Dictionary<A, Info>, but this is not a realy clean way. When I reload A I don't need infos from B. Automapper could be a solution!